# New Web app with accounts

Tags: c#, asp.net, profile, user-accounts

I'm working on a new web application in ASP.NET 2.0 using C#, and in this application there are two key things I need. The first is basic user accounts on the website, and the second is a profile page for the each user. I have some experience with web apps, but I've never done user accounts. Will I need a back-end database?

Can anyone point me to any relevant resources, or help me out themselves?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you will need a database (you can use [Sql Server Express](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Database/), which is free). There's an in-built system for user accounts in asp.net, called [membership](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy.aspx), which you should take a look at. It also supports simple [profiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2y3fs9xs.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

do you want to identify and use the winows user accounts, like the Active Directory ones or you want to create your own user and group lists?

I would say 99% of the cases you would need a database in both cases, if you plan to be able to set which permissions every user or group has on which object and you want to handle group membership as well...

Comment: No I didn't mean Active Directory accounts, I meant online accounts for a website. For example the way every ebay user has an account and a profile page.